# Is it possible to modify the coloring of code inside code blocks in Marp with Markdown?

Tags: markdown, marp

## Changing colors inside code blocks in Markdown

I'm starting to use Marp for some presentations. Now that I need to use code blocks, the syntax coloring seems unsaturated and not modifiable. (I'm on VSCode)

I tried changing themes, and it didn't work. I don't know how I can change it (if it's possible at all)

I can't post images because of my low rep :/

Looking for help with this